# MYSQL: SQL debit / credit

Tags: mysql

Editing my previous question, I simplified (I hope!) my problem.

Let's go.

We have a table like in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42250/1

We have 3 different id_customer, I need to SELECT only that made transactions in two or more id_shop.

In effect I have this data with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_customer)
FROM transaction AS t1
WHERE EXISTS

    (SELECT id_customer
    FROM transaction as t2
    WHERE t2.id_shop_where_transaction_is_done != t1.id_shop_where_transaction_is_done 
    AND t2.id_customer = t1.id_customer)
```

And data are 64982 and 64984.

Now I need to calculate the credit / debit between shop(s), and having a result table like following:

```
+------------+-------+--------+
|            | DEBIT | CREDIT |
+------------+-------+--------+
| TRASTEVERE | 5.50  | 0.00   |
| MONTI      | 2.00  | 5.50   |
| PRATI      | 0.00  | 2.00   |
+------------+-------+--------+
```

**Why "TRASTEVERE" is in debit of 5.50?** Because id_customer 64984 has charged 11.00 in TRASTEVERE and spent 5.50€ in MONTI.

**Why "MONTI" is in credit of 5.50?** Because id_customer 64984 has charged 11.00 in TRASTEVERE and spent 5.50 in MONTI.

Basically, I need to

1) Exclude customers that spent in just one shop (made, see the query above)
2) If a customer charge X in shop A and spend Y in shop B, I need to calculate this and apply credit/debit.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm little confused by id_account 10 = 3 shouldn't that be 6, if it's id_account 11 = -3, then we SUM by id_account and in first we SUM all amount with number 7

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made an edit to clarify that -3. Thank you

Comment: and why dont you take into account [id 2]?

Comment: because customer 7 has charged 10.00 in id_account 10 and that -4 (id 2) is spent in same id_account, so id_account in this case is not in debit/credit with nobody....

Comment: If we have one more row with id 8, id_account 15, customer 7, amount -1 what will be desired result of query? My guess id_account 10 = 2, id account 11 = -4 and id_account 15 = -1

Comment: id_account 10 = 4, id_account 11 = -3, id_account 15 = -1.  Final sum of the accounts need to be zero...

Comment: Sry for all this question but I can't figure out logic behind this. Still can't figure out how id_account 10 is calculated and how for others. :(

Comment: Aleksandar Miladinovic don't worry, you are helping me. See my edit, hoping now it's more clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well I'm doing my best :) Yes it's a little bit clear but still there is a plenty of question like is first transaction that customer make is always is charge, what's happened when customer recharge money... if we have new row like id 9, id_account 15, customer 7, amount 20 how to deal with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84021/discussion-between-aleksandar-miladinovic-and-sineverba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comment and chat we figured out that the solution here (with minimal table structure change) is to be added new column (id_shop_where_money_come_from INT) in table transaction which will hold data which represent account_id where money come from so we can fallow between which two account transfer is made. Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/818bb/25) with added column and query which will output desired result...

GL!

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Good solution and overall... it works like a charme!